# Angular 6 add items into Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I'm new to Angular 6 and i'm having trouble on how i can add objects into observable in a service.

i have this observable

```
 getContacts(){
  return this.contact = 
  this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
 }
```

and i need to add an item into that observable via another function

```
addContact(item){
 //observable insertion goes here.
}
```

Here is my full service code

```
export class ContactService {

contact;
details;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

getContacts(){
 return this.contact = 
 this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
}

addContact(contactName: string, contactPhone: string){

}

}
```

Comment: seems like you need to use RxJS forkJoin

Comment: I do not understand, what you exactly want to achieve. Observables only support you to get messages from your server, they do not directly contain the data themselves. You only get your contact/user data when you `subscribe()` on the observable. The docs explain it better than I do (https://angular.io/guide/observables). Anyway, you probably want to add an item to your contact?

Comment: @gillesB Yes, Exactly that's what i wanted but add contact only on the current instance not in the server

Comment: It is hard to read this as a comment. Please edit your answer and put the code there.

Comment: @gillesB i edit my question. last part is my full service code

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If `this.contacts` is an Observable of list of objects (`contacts: Observable<Items[]>`) and you want to make some changes to that list, you can simply use `tap`:

```
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.contacts.pipe(tap(usersList => {
  usersList.push(newItem);
}));
```

But if you want to make another request to the server and merge these lists, you can use `merge`:

```
import { merge } from 'rxjs';

merge(
  this.contacts,
  this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/other_users');
).pipe(
  map(data => {
    const [currentResult, pastResult] = data;
    // ...
  }
));
```

## Update

Based on your comment for more details, you don't need to do anything with observables. What you need is something like this:

In your `contacts.service.ts`:

```
getContacts(){
  return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
}
```

In your contacts.component.ts`:

```
contacts: any[] = [];
ngOnInit() {
  this.contactsService.getContacts().subscribe(data => {
    this.contacts = data;
  });
}

addContact(item) {
  this.contacts.push(item);
}
```

But if you want to have your contacts list as an Observable, you should use a `Subject`.

In your `contacts.service.ts`:

```
contactsChange$ = new Subject<any>();
private contactsList = [];

getContacts(){
  return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').pipe(tap(data => {
    this.contactsList = data;
    this.contactsChange$.next(this.contactsList);
  }));
}

addContact(item) {
  this.contactsList.push(item);
  this.contactsChange$.next(this.contactsList);
}
```

In your contacts.component.ts`:

```
contacts: any[] = [];
ngOnInit() {
  this.contactsService.getContacts().subscribe(data => {this.contacts = data});
  this.contactsService.contactsChange$.subscribe(data => {this.contacts = data});
}
```

Comment: I tried this one but it seems not working for me. There is no error but i cant see the new added item

Comment: @FrancisRubia When are you subscribing to `this.contacts`? If you do that before calling `addContact`, then you won't see any changes.

Comment: i'm subscribing on init. After the page load i should see those default user from jsonplaceholder.com and after adding a contact i should be able to see the changes from the list. How am i supposed to do it right

Comment: @FrancisRubia I've updated my answer. Check it please.

Comment: Yes, this is actually working but for some reason. I needed to use a service for adding a contact

Comment: @FrancisRubia So then you need to have a Subject in your service. A Subject is like an Observable but you also can use `next` method to add items to it. I'll add the code or using a Subject.

Comment: This is an awesome answer! I'd like to add one small note: The dollar sign should be at the end of the variable name, to make clear that it is an observable/subject and not an event. 
source: https://angular.io/guide/rx-library#naming-conventions-for-observables

Comment: The updated versions of this answer is well done, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Working With Observable**

---

In Your Service

```
private contactInsertedSubject = new Subject<Contact>();
contactInsertedActions$ = this.contactInsertedSubject.asObservable();

 public contacts$ = this.http.get<Contact[]>(this.contactsUrl)
            .pipe(
              // tap(data => console.log('Contacts: ', JSON.stringify(data))),
              catchError(this.handleError)
            );
public contactsWithAdd$ = merge(this.contacts$, this.contactInsertedActions$)
                        .pipe(
                          scan((acc: Product[], value: Product) => [...acc, value])
                        );
addContact(newContact?: Contact) {
   this.contactInsertedSubject.next(newContact);
}
```

---

Your Contact Component Class

```
contacts$ = this.contactService.contactsWithAdd$;
onAdd(): void {
   this.contactService.addProduct();
}
```

when this add method will call the subject in service will emit the value and merge observable has two input observable if any one will emit value so this will call automatically and then in pipe map operator will do the insertion job and contactWithAdd observable will have updated list.

Answer (score 0):

The addContact () method is where you subscribe to the observable getContacts():

```
getContacts(): Observable<any> {   
    return this.contact = 
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
}
```

At the time of subscription is when the call is triggered:

```
addContact(){
    let cont: Observable<contactModel>;
    cont = this.getContacts();
    prueba.finally(() => {
       console.log('Finally callback')
    })
    cont.subscribe(res => {
        console.log('at the time of subscription is when the call is triggered')
        let resp: contactModel[];
        resp = res.json() as contactModel[];  
    });


}
```