# How to add item to rxjs observable array?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a component that gets data from server. My service has a `BehaviorSubject<any[]>([])` to get data.

```
export class AppComponent {
  items: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(private service: MyService) {
    this.items = service.getItems();
    // this items format is like: `[{id:1,name:'cat'},{id:2,name:'dog'}]`
  }

  addItem(item:any){
   // add item to `this.items` observable array ???
  }

  removeItem(item:any){
   // remove item from `this.items` observable array ???
  }
}
```

And my service is like following:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService{
    private items = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
      this.loadItems();
    }

    private loadItems() {
      this.http.get<any[]>('/api/items')
        .subscribe((i) => this.items.next(i));
    }

    getItems() {
      return this.items.asObservable();
    }

    addItem(item: any) {
      return this.http
        .post<any>('/api/items', item)
        .subscribe(() => this.loadItems());
    }
}
```

I need to add add and remove an item to this observable array but could not do it. The service can add data to server, but I need to add array without send to server. Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 6 add items into Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53260269/angular-6-add-items-into-observable)

Comment: It's possibly a duplicate as posted by @jitender. On another note: Please also share the code within `MyService`.

Comment: Are you assign array into `BehaviourSubject` (`BehaviorSubject<any[]>([])`) that you need the array to be added into another array (`items: Observable<any[]>;`)?

Comment: @varman no I did not. Should I add? Can you type solution as answer?

Comment: So you need to pass only one value to behaviour subject and put into the array, isn't it?

Comment: Please brief actually what you need to add and remove that we can help you

Comment: @varman I need to add and remove item from `this.items` observable array in component, I do not want to add to service. I updated the post.

Comment: `service.getItems()` returns array or array object?

Comment: Not it returns an observable array.

Comment: What I asked you is, is that returning like `['cat','dog','rabbit']` or `[{id:1,name:'cat'},{id:2,name:'dog'},{id:3,name:'rabbit'}]`. Please clearly mention what is your question

Comment: It returns object array `[{id:1,name:'cat'},{id:2,name:'dog'},{id:3,name:'rabbit'}]` as you said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case you don't need to define `BehaviourSubject`, because you are not maintaining state over the application. So simply you can use like following.

In your service component, write only the service. Because service is a singleton which is only one time initialized.

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeDataService {    

    //Made this as observable, But when you use httpClient, No need to use Observable.of(), you can directly return like this.http.get<any[]>('/api/items')

    myData=Observable.of([{id:1,name:'cat'},{id:2,name:'dog'},{id:3,name:'rabbit'}])
    constructor() {     
    }

    loadItems() {
      // in your case, return this.http.get<any[]>('/api/items')
      return this.myData;
    }
}
```

In the AppComponent

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    counter=4;
    mydata=[]; //No point to make this as Observable array

    constructor(private _service: SomeDataService) { }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this._service.loadItems().subscribe(res=>{     
            this.mydata=res;       
        })  
    }

    addData(){
        let increment=this.counter++
        let data={id:increment,name:increment+"data"}
        this.mydata.push(data)
    }

    removeData(item){
        let index=this.mydata.indexOf(item)
        this.mydata = this.mydata.filter((val,i) => i!=index); 
    }
}
```

In html,

```
<button (click)="addData()">Add data</button>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let data of mydata;let i=index;">
        <td>{{data.id}}</td>
        <td>{{data.name}}</td>
        <td><button (click)="removeData(data)">Remove data</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Click here for the demo [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/behaviorsubject-example-ulpmyv).

Comment: Hi Varman. Please do not roll back good edits here, or add chatty/conversational material to posts. Technical writing is preferred. If you are not familiar with the guidelines for succinct writing, please let me know, so I can point you to some relevant posts on _Meta_.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to subscribe to the observables and return the values, before you can do any further manipulation.

For instance,

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  items: any[];

  constructor(private service: MyService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getItems().subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.items = res;
    });
  }

addItem(){
  // this.items.push(someObject)
}


}
```