# How to find or add items in/ to an Obersavble of type array in Angular and rxjs?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, angular9

The user can load companies by `id` via a `CompanyService`. As the company will not change throughout the life time of the application, I thought it would make sense to cache all already loaded items and load new ones only if needed.

Now I came up with this solution that works using an local `Array<Company>` as the cache. It returns `of()` of a found elment and alternativley loads a new one and stores it in the cache.

```
export class CompanyService {
  private cache: Array<Company> = [];
  private path: string = '';

  getById(id: number): Observable<Company> {
    const company = this.cache.find(item => item.id === id);

    if (company) {
      return of(company);
    }

    return this.http.get<any>(this.path + id).pipe(
      map(response => {
        this.cache.push(response);
        return response;
      }),
      catchError(error => {
        return of(null);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Is this the right way to do it?

I thought it might be better to use something like:

```
private cache$: Observable<Array<Company>>;
```

But I don't know:

- … whether this is a better approach?
- … how to add a new item?
- … how find an item in this `Observable` and return a new one otherwise?

Comment: This could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53260507/12193298

Comment: Yes, so the components are using the service? then it is better to use the observable approach. and then with emit you can pass the values.

Comment: @savantTheCoder Yes, Components use the service. That's why I thought the Obersavble approach would be better, as you endorse.

Comment: Yes, I put it as a ans ware. you can vote on it, if that is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do is: providing this service in root, first of all.
Start with returning observable if it needs to return one.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CompanyService {
  private cache:Company[] = [];
  private path: string = '';

  getById(id: number): Observable<Company> {
    return new Observable(subs=>{
      const company = this.cache.find(item => item.id === id);
      if(!company){
        this.http.get<Company>(this.path + id).subscribe(result=>{
          this.cache.push(result);
          subs.next(result);
        });
      } else {
        subs.next(company);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

You might need to implement null check and handle errors. 
I hope you'll find it helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could yuo explain what the difference to the current solution is? It seems, that it is doing the same thing a bit more complicated.